# PostGIS/GEOS strange TopologyException

Tags: geos

How can this happen

```
mv_kuvio=> select id,st_isvalid(geom) from x;
 id  | st_isvalid 
-----+------------
 376 | t
(1 row)
```

```
mv_kuvio=> select k.id,st_isvalid(k.geom) from kuvio k, x where st_intersects(k.geom,st_envelope(x.geom));
    id    | st_isvalid 
----------+------------
 26529854 | t
 26529852 | t
 26529853 | t
 26529849 | t
 42934164 | t
(5 rows)
```

```
mv_kuvio=> select k.id,st_intersects(k.geom,x.geom) from kuvio k, x where k.id in (26529854,26529852,26529853,26529849,42934164);
    id    | st_intersects 
----------+---------------
 26529849 | t
 26529852 | t
 26529853 | t
 26529854 | t
 42934164 | f
(5 rows)
```

But then

```
mv_kuvio=> select k.id,st_isvalid(k.geom) from kuvio k, x where st_intersects(k.geom,x.geom);
ERROR:  GEOSIntersects: TopologyException: side location conflict at 640573.94828713115 6923639.6320446655. This can occur if the input geometry is invalid.
```

One would assume that the last one would not do anything that is done in those above it.